# CoreData relationship from one entity to one-of-many entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'd like to create a CoreData model which achieves the following:

I have various different types of entity (Comment, Image, User, etc.) which all have the same 10 fields on them (i.e. isSent, isReceived, isAuthorised, authorisationDate, etc.)

Rather than add these 10 fields to every record, I'd like to create a single entity (called Measurement) with these on them, and each of my other entities to have a one-to-one relationship with a Measurement entity.

I could do this by having a uni-directional relationship, but I would like the relationship to be bi-directional (so that I can grab, say, all the authorised Measurements, and track what they are (whether they are a Comment, Image, User etc.)

Is there an inverse relationship where I don't specify the type of the inverse entity?  Or do I need to add a separate relationship for each inverse entity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not a good domain model: these classes should be named something else, e.g. UserMeasurement. What I would suggest is you think about doing a model where you have Measurement as a base, abstract class and then do classes for each of the entity types. CoreData can do inheritance quite well actually. If you have experience with ORMs like Hibernate, it's quite different, but very easy to setup. These things all satisfy the is a requirement for inheritance, and there should be no way to measure nothing (which is why the base should be abstract).

Here's [the location](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html) in the CoreData docs that discusses this.

Comment: That sounds EXACTLY like what I want to do.  Make measurement the base class and make the other inherit from it.  I'll look into setting that up now.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the names were simplified.

Comment: CoreData is actually really good for this kind of stuff. Furthermore, you will be able to put some of the most generic fetch logic in a base class which would be nice too, e.g. fetchCurrentState -> the most recent measurement of the given type.

Comment: One thing to keep in the back of your mind (very far back) is that if using sqlite this will create one table with all the properties of the subclasses in it - so you could end up with your whole app running from one just table if you go overboard on inheriting.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create an `Abstract Entity` which all of these classes inherit from called `Measurable` and the relationship could live there.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds spot on.  I'll look into that now. Thanks!